# How do I create a WPF Image control that sources its data from a JPEG I've read into memory?

Tags: wpf, image, jpeg, in-memory

For the images in my application, I have been setting the `source` property of my image to a JPEG file on disk but, as part of my next iteration, I want to test keeping them in memory for speed.

How do I tell the WPF Image control to get its information from an in-memory source rather than from a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [InteropBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.interopbitmap.aspx) and [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx), two classes that inherit from BitmapSource that allow you to supply the pixels of the image from an array.

To create an InteropBitmap you use methods on the Imaging class like [Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromMemorySection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.imaging.createbitmapsourcefrommemorysection.aspx).